# RunPE dump process

Tags: delphi, winapi, process, dump

Is it possible to dump its own process when it got started from runpe?

Where would be the startaddress of the process, etc.?

EDIT:

I have this unit to run an executable from memory:

```
unit uExecFromMem;

interface

uses Windows;

function ExecuteFromMem(szFilePath:string; pFile:Pointer):DWORD;

type
  PImageBaseRelocation = ^TImageBaseRelocation;
  TImageBaseRelocation = packed record
     VirtualAddress: DWORD;
     SizeOfBlock: DWORD;
  end;

function NtUnmapViewOfSection(ProcessHandle:DWORD; BaseAddress:Pointer):DWORD; stdcall; external 'ntdll';

implementation

procedure PerformBaseRelocation(f_module: Pointer; INH:PImageNtHeaders; f_delta: Cardinal); stdcall;
var
  l_i: Cardinal;
  l_codebase: Pointer;
  l_relocation: PImageBaseRelocation;
  l_dest: Pointer;
  l_relInfo: ^Word;
  l_patchAddrHL: ^DWord;
  l_type, l_offset: integer;
begin
  l_codebase := f_module;
  if INH^.OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[5].Size > 0 then
  begin
    l_relocation := PImageBaseRelocation(Cardinal(l_codebase) + INH^.OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[5].VirtualAddress);
    while l_relocation.VirtualAddress > 0 do
    begin
      l_dest := Pointer((Cardinal(l_codebase) + l_relocation.VirtualAddress));
      l_relInfo := Pointer(Cardinal(l_relocation) + 8);
      for l_i := 0 to (trunc(((l_relocation.SizeOfBlock - 8) / 2)) - 1) do
      begin
        l_type := (l_relInfo^ shr 12);
        l_offset := l_relInfo^ and $FFF;
        if l_type = 3 then
        begin
          l_patchAddrHL := Pointer(Cardinal(l_dest) + Cardinal(l_offset));
          l_patchAddrHL^ := l_patchAddrHL^ + f_delta;
        end;
        inc(l_relInfo);
      end;
      l_relocation := Pointer(cardinal(l_relocation) + l_relocation.SizeOfBlock);
    end;
  end;
end;

function AlignImage(pImage:Pointer):Pointer;
var
  IDH:          PImageDosHeader;
  INH:          PImageNtHeaders;
  ISH:          PImageSectionHeader;
  i:            WORD;
begin
  IDH := pImage;
  INH := Pointer(DWORD(pImage) + IDH^._lfanew);
  GetMem(Result, INH^.OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage);
  ZeroMemory(Result, INH^.OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage);
  CopyMemory(Result, pImage, INH^.OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders);
  for i := 0 to INH^.FileHeader.NumberOfSections - 1 do
  begin
    ISH := Pointer(DWORD(pImage) + IDH^._lfanew + 248 + i * 40);
    CopyMemory(Pointer(DWORD(Result) + ISH^.VirtualAddress), Pointer(DWORD(pImage) + ISH^.PointerToRawData), ISH^.SizeOfRawData);
  end;
end;

function ExecuteFromMem(szFilePath:string; pFile:Pointer):DWORD;
var
  PI:           TProcessInformation;
  SI:           TStartupInfo;
  CT:           TContext;
  IDH:          PImageDosHeader;
  INH:          PImageNtHeaders;
  dwImageBase:  DWORD;
  pModule:      Pointer;
  dwNull:       DWORD;
begin
  Result := 0;
  IDH := pFile;
  if IDH^.e_magic = IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE then
  begin
    INH := Pointer(DWORD(pFile) + IDH^._lfanew);
    if INH^.Signature = IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE then
    begin
      FillChar(SI, SizeOf(TStartupInfo), #0);
      FillChar(PI, SizeOf(TProcessInformation), #0);
      SI.cb := SizeOf(TStartupInfo);
      if CreateProcess(nil, PChar(szFilePath), nil, nil, FALSE, CREATE_SUSPENDED, nil, nil, SI, PI) then
      begin
        CT.ContextFlags := CONTEXT_FULL;
        if GetThreadContext(PI.hThread, CT) then
        begin
          ReadProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, Pointer(CT.Ebx + 8), @dwImageBase, 4, dwNull);
          if dwImageBase = INH^.OptionalHeader.ImageBase then
          begin
            if NtUnmapViewOfSection(PI.hProcess, Pointer(INH^.OptionalHeader.ImageBase)) = 0 then
              pModule := VirtualAllocEx(PI.hProcess, Pointer(INH^.OptionalHeader.ImageBase), INH^.OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage, MEM_COMMIT or MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE)
            else
              pModule := VirtualAllocEx(PI.hProcess, nil, INH^.OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage, MEM_COMMIT or MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
          end
          else
            pModule := VirtualAllocEx(PI.hProcess, Pointer(INH^.OptionalHeader.ImageBase), INH^.OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage, MEM_COMMIT or MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
          if pModule <> nil then
          begin
            pFile := AlignImage(pFile);
            if DWORD(pModule) <> INH^.OptionalHeader.ImageBase then
            begin
              PerformBaseRelocation(pFile, INH, (DWORD(pModule) - INH^.OptionalHeader.ImageBase));
              INH^.OptionalHeader.ImageBase := DWORD(pModule);
              CopyMemory(Pointer(DWORD(pFile) + IDH^._lfanew), INH, 248);
            end;
            WriteProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, pModule, pFile, INH.OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage, dwNull);
            WriteProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, Pointer(CT.Ebx + 8), @pModule, 4, dwNull);
            CT.Eax := DWORD(pModule) + INH^.OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint;
            SetThreadContext(PI.hThread, CT);
            ResumeThread(PI.hThread);
            FreeMem(pFile, INH^.OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage);
            Result := PI.hThread;
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Then I have Application1 and Application2.

Application1 has Application2 (the complete executable) stored in memory.
Then Application1 starts Application2 from memory like this:

```
ExecuteFromMem(paramstr(0), @Application2InMemory) // uses Application1 as Host
```

Now Application2 is loaded in memory and is started!
How can Application2 get the it's data (the Application2.exe) back to the disk (or back to a var)?

Comment: What does "dump its own process" mean? And what do you mean by "start address" of a process? And what do you mean by "when it got started from runpe"? RunPE works by starting a process suspected. Pretty hard to do anything when suspended.

Comment: I mean how can I get the .exe file that got loaded into an application? The complete file is in memory

Comment: Can we have more details. I can't work out what you are doing?

Comment: I'm sorry. I edited my question. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: Why do this in app2. Easier to do it in app1.

Comment: App2 is loaded in memory and doesn't know where it's original file came from. That's why I would like to dump it.

Comment: If you want the file on disk, stop using the code in the question. Save it to disk and execute it normally. People only use in memory loaders to avoid having to put the file on disk. If you want the file on disk then there's no point to in memory loaders. Also, in memory loaders are the hallmark of malware. Use them and expect AV software to take an interest in your program.

Comment: The main reason for this is to "update" an application. App1 downloads a new executable from the net and stores it in memory. After that the downloaded file get's executed in memory. Then Application1 closes itself (so the handle to access the file is free). App2 has now access to the filepath with the filename to overwrite App1. Update done.

Comment: Oh I see. No need for in memory loaders here at all! Download to a temp file. Then start a new process to apply the update. That waits until the first program has unloaded. Then copies the temp file to the executable location, overwriting the original exe file. And then starts up the new executable. That's how it's meant to be done. For what it's worth, in memory loaders are completely unsupported on Windows and almost invariably used by malware. And AV software knows this.

Comment: Thank you this should do it. Too bad there is no way to dump it tho.

Comment: Oh, I'm sure you can dump it. All the structures you need are in the code you posted. I just urge you not to use in memory loaders for such a trivial and mundane task as updating an app. In fact don't use in memory loaders every. For anything. Well, apart from for a bit of fun!!

Comment: BTW: this fails with application that load resources such as strings (MUI) because they try to load it from Application1.Exe.dll instead of Application2.exe.dll. Try it with for instance notepad in windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are launching Application1 again from Application1 but suspended. Before resuming Application1 you are loading Application2 from disk and copy it to the address in memory of (the seconds instance of) Application1. The attached code takes care of copying the PE Header, DOS Header, NT Headers, Optional Headers and so on and adjusting relocations if required.

Effectively you *have* Application2 in memory it's just being called Application1 in Task Manager. Therefore if you dump Application2 to disk from Application2 you will get Application2, try it!

Comment: "You are launching Application1 again from Application1" - I actually launch Application2 from Application1.

Comment: The process is in memory. You know the base address. It's `HINSTANCE` in Delphi code. `INH^.OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage` gives you the size. Dump that to disk and you are done. It's still a diabolically bad idea for an updater!

Comment: @BenjaminWeiss: Noooo, first param of ExecuteFromMem is ParamStr(0) which is "self" (Application1) this is the launched application in the CreateProcess call...

Comment: @BenjaminWeiss Is there any reason why you didn't accept this answer?